# ENV vs ATTR in udev rules?

Tags: udev

I'm trying to automount a usb to my raspberry pi, but I can't seem to get my udev rule to work.

The code I'm using is:

```
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Flash_Drive", RUN+="bin/mkdir /home/pi/heyimhere"
```

This doesn't work as no directory at that location is created as the flash drive is being plugged in.

I had luck using usb to shut down using the same rules, this time shutting it down using this line:

```
ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Flash_Drive", RUN+="sbin/shutdown -h now"
```

Which works - as soon as you remove the usb it shuts down.

Why? Should I use ATTR for add?

Comment: A udev rule is the wrong approach. You want `SYSTEMD_WANTS`; see `man systemd.device`.

Answer (score 2):

## ENV vs ATTR/ATTRS

[ATTR{filename}](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#ATTR%7Bfilename%7D)
  Match sysfs attribute values of the event device.

[ATTRS{filename}](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#ATTRS%7Bfilename%7D)
  Search the devpath upwards for a device with matching sysfs attribute values. **If multiple ATTRS matches are specified, all of them must match on the same device.**

[ENV{key}](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#ENV%7Bkey%7D)
  Match against a device property value.

If both `ENV` and `ATTR` contain the same information - you can use any of them, there is no any difference.

`ENV`s for the device in question can contain values derived from different parent devices. So with `ENV`s you can sometimes match on values from several parent devices simultaneously, which is impossible with `ATTRS`.

## Rule for creating a directory

You must use absolute path in [`RUN`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#RUN%7Btype%7D) key (`RUN+="/bin/mkdir /home/pi/heyimhere"` in your example):

> If no absolute path is given, the program is expected to live in /usr/lib/udev; otherwise, **the absolute path must be specified**.

By the way, I don't know why your shutdown rule works. It shouldn't, because of `sbin/shutdown` without leading `/`.

## Mounting from udev rules

As jasonwryan [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401432/env-vs-attr-in-udev-rules#comment719692_401432), [you can't use udev for automount](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#RUN%7Btype%7D):

> Note that running programs that access the network or **mount/unmount filesystems is not allowed inside of udev rules**, due to the default sandbox that is enforced on systemd-udevd.service.

Comment: Note that the `ENV{key}` attributes may be *defined by earlier rules*, so if you use them, your rule must come *after* some other rule that defines the corresponding key with `ENV{key}=<something>`. The `ENV{key}` attributes will also be available as environment variables for any programs you might run with the `PROGRAM=` rule element.